# create new web service using existing web service

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I am using .NET Framework 4 and Visual Studio 2010 Express edition. I only have a couple of features like class library but no option to open WCF or create any web service.

I have a web service in my local system, which i could see in the available web references,  but now i need to create another web service using all the methods and classes of the existing web service. How can I do that?

Do I have to create a new class and add this web reference? If so, can you please post me a sample piece of code for doing that?

The only change required in my existing web service is the web service namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to follow [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx.aspx) from MSDN.